# How do I get a popup form working in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I am developing a simple CRUD application with .NET Framework and MS SQL Server. It has one page that will display all rows in the database and a button for adding new rows. For the button I want to display a popup form where the new row information will be added.

I am having trouble getting the popup to work. When I click the add button nothing happens. There must be an issue with the scrips. I have looked over it 100 times and can't find the issue. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Position Type";
}

<h2>Add/Edit</h2>

<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddorEdit", "Job_Lookup_PositionType")')"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add</a>
<table class="table" id="positionTable" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>JobDescURL</th>
            <th>UseCrewType</th>
            <th>IsValid</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>OtherHTML</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<!-- CSS For making table into a jQuery data table -->
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- CLink for Font Awesome icons -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@section scripts{
    <!-- jQuery For making table into a jQuery data table -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <!-- This script describes how the table will be displayed -->
    <script>
        var Popup, dataTable;
        dataTable = $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#positionTable").DataTable({
                "paging": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "info": false,
                "search": false
                        "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Position/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "JobDescURL" },
                    { "data": "UseCrewType" },
                    { "data": "IsValid" },
                    { "data": "Comments" },
                    { "data": "OtherHTML" }
                ]
            });
        });

        function PopupForm(url) {
            var formDiv = $('<div/>');
            $.get(url)
                .done(function (response) {
                    formDiv.html(response);

                    Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        title: 'Add new Position',
                        height: 500,
                        width: 700,
                        close: function () {
                            Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                        }
                        });
                });
        }
    </script>

}
```

Comment: At first sight I see a couple of issues. 1) Instead of this `dataTable = $(document).ready(function ()` it should be `dataTable = $("#positionTable").DataTable({`. 2) You're missing a comma after `"search": false`.

Comment: @Sagnalrac thanks for the input but this has not resolved the popup issue